# Prove that $a$ and $b$ have a coproduct in $C$ iff $C(a, -) \times C(b, -)$ is representable

Tags: category-theory

From Mac Lane's Category theory:

> Prove that $a$ and $b$ have a coproduct in $C$ iff $C(a, -) \times C(b, -)$ is representable.

I can see that if $a,b$ have a coproduct $a \coprod b$, then the representation is $\psi : C(a, -) \times C(b,-)\rightarrow C(a \coprod b, -)$ with $\psi : \langle f=u \circ i,g = u \circ j \rangle \mapsto u$ where $u$ is the unique map in the coproduct diagram.

But I'm having trouble proving the reverse direction.  I can't see exactly how I'd find an $i: a \rightarrow r$ and $j : b \rightarrow r$ such that the coproduct requirement holds.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: By assumption there is a representing object...

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed from that.  I see that that means $C(a,-) \times C(b, -) \cong C(r,-)$ is a natural isomorphism, but I can't see how to choose an $i,j$ such that there's a unique $u : r \rightarrow d$ such that for every $f : a \rightarrow d$ and $g : b \rightarrow d$ it must be the case that $u \circ i = f, u \circ j = g$.

Comment: Consider the identity case.

Comment: @DerekElkins Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Derek Elkins gave you what you need. Suppose $r$ is the representing object, so there is a natural equivalence of functors $\eta: C(a,-) \times C(b,-) \to C(r,-)$.  The point, of course, is that $r$ serves as a coproduct of $a$ and $b$.  So, you need only check that $r$ satisfies the right universal mapping property.  For this, you need the coproduct "inclusion" maps.  Evaluate $\eta$ at $r$ so that we have a bijection
$$
\eta_r:  C(a,r) \times C(b,r) \to C(r,r).
$$
Hence  we have $\eta_r(\alpha, \beta)=1_r$ for a unique pair of maps $\alpha: a \to r$ and $\beta : b \to r$.  Now, check that the setup $(r, \alpha, \beta)$ meets all the properties of the coproduct $a \amalg b$.  It does, and for this you will need the naturality of $\eta$.

**Addendum:**  Take all the setup and notation above.  Suppose we are given two arbitrary maps $u: a \to d$ and $v: b \to d$ for some object $d$.  We must show there is a unique $f: r \to d$ such that $f \circ \alpha =u$ and $f \circ \beta = v$.  Evaluate $\eta$ at $d$ (*honestly, the only thing you could do here*) to get the bijection 
$$
\eta_d: C(a,d) \times C(b,d) \to C(r,d).
$$
Put $f=\eta_d(u,v)$.  This solves the commutativity problems by naturality:
$$
(f_* \circ \eta_r)(\alpha, \beta) = f_*(1_r)= f
$$
around two legs of the square while the other two legs give
$$
(\eta_d \circ (f_* \times f_*))(\alpha, \beta) = \eta_d (f\circ \alpha, f\circ \beta).
$$
**But by naturality this has to be $f$**, so 
$$
\eta_d (f\circ \alpha, f\circ \beta) =  f = \eta_d(u,v).
$$
But $\eta_d$ is one-to-one, so $f \circ \alpha = u$ and $f \circ \beta =v$. To show that $f$ is unique.... (you should handle this)

Comment: Can you explain how naturality shows that $(r, \alpha, \beta)$ meets the requirements of the coproduct?  I see that naturality means $C(r,k) \circ \psi_r=\psi_d \circ C(a,k) \times C(b,k) $ where $k$ is some map in $C$ from $r$ to $d$, but I can't see how a map between functions can show that any two maps $f:a \rightarrow d$ and $g : b \rightarrow d$ must have a unique map that commutes through $r$.  Specifically if we have $\psi_d$ and $f,g$ and $u$, why can we say $u \circ \alpha = f, u \circ \beta = g$?

Comment: I'll add it, but it really is the exact same statement that my $\eta$ is natural (like all categorical arguments:   they should prove themselves).

Comment: @OliverG  I should add that it matters that $\eta$ is a natural equivalence, not just a run of the mill natural transformation.